# Is there a way in gmock to return modified input arg without invoke?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I want to do something like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*mock, method(5)).WillOnce(Return(arg1 * 2));
```

where arg1 should be equal to first arg of called method. Is there a way to do that without `testing::Invoke`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method 1:**

You can use a custom matcher, as the other answer mentioned, however, notice that the preferred way of using custom matchers is by using functors, not the `ACTION` macro (See [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#legacy-macro-based-actions)).

Here is an example:

```
// Define a functor first:
struct Double {
  template <typename T>
  T operator()(T arg) {
    return 2 * (arg);
  }
};


TEST(MyTest, CanDoubleWithFunctor) {
  MyMock mock;

  // Use the functor in the test:
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, method(5)).WillOnce(Double{});

  EXPECT_EQ(mock.method(5), 10);
}
```

See a working example here: https://godbolt.org/z/h4aaPdWMs

---

**Method 2:**

Besides the custom matcher, you can use `WithArg` [see here](http://google.github.io/googletest/reference/actions.html#composite-actions), and pass the first argument to it, which will then be passed to a function that takes one argument. This function can be standalone, or a lambda function:

```cpp
class MyMock {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, method, (int), ());
};

TEST(MyTest, CanDouble) {
  MyMock mock;

  EXPECT_CALL(mock, method(5)).WillOnce(WithArg<0>([](int x) {
    return x * 2;
  }));

  EXPECT_EQ(mock.method(5), 10);
}
```

See this [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/E7WbheM7E).

Answer (score 2):

You can define custom action for that:

```cpp
ACTION(ReturnDoubled) {
    return arg0 * 2;
}

class Mock {
   public:
    MOCK_METHOD(int, method, (int), ());
};

TEST(Foo, bar) {
    Mock mock;
    EXPECT_CALL(mock, method(5)).WillOnce(ReturnDoubled());

    ASSERT_EQ(mock.method(5), 10);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dare654Yj

Comment: Please notice that notice that the preferred way of using custom matchers is by using functors, not the `ACTION` macro. Reference: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#legacy-macro-based-actions